# when does ts_rank returns a value of 1

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Im running the next query on my postgresql (9.6)

```
select 
    ts_rank(
        setweight(
            to_tsvector('bed'),
            'A'
        ),
        to_tsquery('bed')
    );
```

i was expecting to get a 1 (the words are the same), but i'm getting

```
ts_rank  
----------
0.607927
```

Doing a different query:

```
select 
    ts_rank(
        setweight(
            to_tsvector('bed sofa'),
            'A'
        ),
        to_tsquery('bed & sofa')
    );
```

and surprise! this is the result

```
 ts_rank  
----------
 0.991032
```

as long as i add more words the value is closer to 1

```
select 
    ts_rank(
        setweight(
            to_tsvector('bed sofa table'),
            'A'
        ),
        to_tsquery('bed & sofa & table')
    );
```

returns

```
 ts_rank  
----------
 0.999999
```

but i dont want this, i hope to get a 1 when the words are the same, besides the number of them

another test, this time with | instead of &

```
select 
    ts_rank(
        setweight(
            to_tsvector('bed sofa table sky'),
            'A'
        ),
        to_tsquery('bed | sofa | table'),
        0
    );
```

this returns

```
 ts_rank  
----------
 0.607927
```

this is not wanted behavior either, for the purpose of my application i also need this to return 1

how is this behavior explained? how can i get a perfect 1 with ts_rank? i can't wrap my head around this

Comment: currently trying with ts_rank_cd

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It is for ranking, the absolute value shouldn't matter.

Comment: its for ranking, the problem is that in the ranking i am mixing another data that are not text. Like the number of rating of the sorted product. 
ts_rank(stuff) + (number_of_stars * 0.1). 0.1 because is the weight of a 'D'. But for this to work i expect the ts_rank to give correct numbers between 1 and 0.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to read the source for details, but experiments show that the rank exceeds 0.6 as soon as a single word matches.

So you could simply create a function that adjusts the rank the way you want:

```
CREATE FUNCTION adj_rank(float4) RETURNS float4
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$SELECT LEAST($1 / 0.6::float4, 1.0::float4)$$;
```